# TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.ga [as copy]

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using angularjs to make a http.get request to a webapi and I am getting TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.ga [as copy]. I am new in angularjs and webapi. I also noticed that when I pass data.id into an alert it return undefined. I have tried all the solution I googled online.

[image]

```
angular.module('schoolManager').controller('UsersController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "dataService", function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, dataService) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.roles = [];
    $scope.editItem = {};
    $scope.isNewItem = false;
    $scope.focusInput = false;
    var baseAddress = 'http://localhost:49535/api/account';


  $scope.loadEditForm = function (id) {
        //$scope.loadRoles(id);
        if (!id) {
            $scope.editItem = {};
            $scope.isNewItem = true;
            $("#modal-user-edit").modal();
            $scope.focusInput = true;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $scope.isNewItem = false;
        }
        $scope.loading = true;
        dataService.getItems(baseAddress + '/' + id)
        .success(function (data) {
            alert(data.UserId);
            angular.copy(data, $scope.editItem);
            $("#modal-user-edit").modal();
            $scope.focusInput = true;
            $scope.loading = false;
        })
        .error(function () {
            toastr.error($rootScope.lbl.errorLoadingUser);
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
    $scope.load();


}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from what is provided, however the error says "cb-{item.Username}" and perhaps that should be cb-{{item.Username}}

Comment: The error I referring to starts from `TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.ga [as copy]`